# corosync 2Node vs two_node flags

Tags: corosync

is the **`2node`** equivalent to the **`two_node`** flag ? Is it the same ?

```
[root@srv1 ~]# corosync-quorumtool -s
Quorum information
------------------
Date:             Wed Mar 20 04:49:10 2019
Quorum provider:  corosync_votequorum
Nodes:            2
Node ID:          1
Ring ID:          1/464
Quorate:          Yes

Votequorum information
----------------------
Expected votes:   2
Highest expected: 2
Total votes:      2
Quorum:           1
Flags:            2Node Quorate WaitForAll

Membership information
----------------------
    Nodeid      Votes Name
         1          1 srv1cr1 (local)
         2          1 srv2cr1
```

http://people.redhat.com/ccaulfie/docs/Votequorum_Intro.pdf

I was not able to find an answer to my question and the documentation is referencing **`two_node`** only.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this article covers your question:  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1295713

> When creating a two node cluster with RHEL7's pacemaker the parameter 'two_node' is
> automatically set for corosync.
>
> The following outputs are from a cluster created with the pcs command without the
> 'two_node' option being specifically mentioned:

```
Quorum:           1                                <----
Flags:            2Node Quorate WaitForAll         <----
```

> The 'two_node' parameter sets the quorum to '1' and allows one node to remain quorate
> and continue cluster operations after the second one is fenced.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get "access denied" accessing that link.  Do you have a pointer to the information somewhere else?

Comment: Perhaps they "retired" that article, @jules?  A search for some of the text doesn't seem to yield the article on Red Hat.  Perhaps there's something there for subscribers.

Comment: We can look at the [source](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acorosync%2Fcorosync%202node&type=code) and there it is clear that two_node is how we set the flag.  The flag itself is stored and masked as VOTEQUORUM_INFO_TWONODE, and the status command displays the flag concisely as '2node'.